# Can you see the "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" off-topic option?

Tags: discussion

I've been seeing lots of questions (well a few) marked as "off-topic" for DSP.SE, with just the "This question does not appear to be about signal processing within the scope defined in the help center." option chosen.

Several of them actually belong on another StackExchange site (usually Math.SE or EE.SE), but I've never seen someone suggest that.

If you suggest that, it makes it easier for me and the other mods to migrate the question to the appropriate site.

[image]

When I click on that option, I get the ability to search for the right Stack Exchange site:

[image]

Comment: It appears to have gone from a choice between meta.dsp and -- nothing.  So all I can do is vote to close because it's off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I see exactly those off-topic options

Comment: Thanks, Olli!!!

Comment: Can you check the next step, to see if the search option is there?

Comment: It is not, only  "belongs on meta.dsp.stackexchange.com
discussion, support, and feature requests for this site
"

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was wondering.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I've been always able to see that option. Unfortunately the only choice, to click there, was our dsp meta site. No option for math, ee, etc. Unless I am missing something...

---

After reading the info about [site graduation](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/congratulations-signal-processing-is-graduating), I noticed the following point:

> You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of
>   the network

Maybe this is the reason why users (except of moderators) can't cast the vote for another network? It also means that it will be resolved soon, once beta is finished.

Comment: See my addition. I get the option of searching for another SE site. This may have only happened since the site was promoted late last year.

Comment: Can't remember before. Now the search is present.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because choosing another site migrates the question automatically, and you have to enough rep (or be a mod) to do that.

Comment: Thanks @datageist! That clears it up.

Comment: @datageist: answer updated - this might be a "beta feature".

Comment: @jojek Nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've been wondering about this, and I just checked it again: the only option I get is DSP meta, which is usually not what I'd want to choose.

[image]

Looks like only mods have that additional option of choosing another SE site. It would be good if other users (with sufficient rep) could do the same.